Tizen webapp - cannot get preferences values
I'm working on a tizen webapp for smart TV.
I need to work on preferences, and I'm struggling to get preferences values.
In config.xml file I have put the following lines:
<preference name="pref1" value="1">
<preference name="pref2" value="2">
<preference name="pref3" value="3">
I'm trying to access preferences value with:
const pref1 = tizen.preference.getValue('pref1');
When I run my app on simulator and I open the console I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getValue')
Inspecting the code I see tizen is initalizated but tizen.preference is undefined.
What am I doing wrong?

Hello, have you added items via Preferences Tab or via directly editing config.xml file? When I used Preferences Tab, an Iteam was added like this: 

I added items editing config.xml, and then going on Prefereces Tab I see them

tizen.preference is just not supported on Tizen TV, so you cannot use it. Full list of supported modules is here, but Preference module is not listed.
Preference is supported for mobile and wearable only.

So, how can I store and edit application settings for Tizen TV webapp?

How about to use Tizen TV specific API? https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/widgetdata-api.html

Probably you can find some useful APIs also in section https://docs.tizen.org/application/web/api/5.5/w3c_api/w3c_api_m.html#storage

@LunchBasketball I tried the example code and webapis.widgetdata.write(data, onsuccess, onerror); fails.
it goes in the catch(error) where error.message = "password is not defined"
